# Replace %26 with ampersand

Tags: php, url, ampersand

Every piece of research I look up refers to replacing the ampersand with %26, when in fact I want to replace %26 in the URL with the ampersand.

At the moment each time I pass the url under the GET command I get %26 back.

For example the code I am passing in the form is as follows

```
    <form method="get" action="<?php echo $SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

    <input type="text" id="stg" name="stg" size = "25" value="<?php echo '?pn=' . $sub1 .'%26'.$jrny.'&Subject='.$Subject.'&pn2='.$sub1. '&arc='.$sess.'&Table_Id='.$Table_Id; ;?>" />
```

When I try string replace or rawurlencode functions I still end up with %26. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have a query string in the value-Field of your input? The browser will obviously think that this needs to be escaped when the request URL is built and thus encodes the ampersand in there. If you need multiple values in your GET request, use multiple input fields and the browser will suddenly do the right thing.

Comment: Thanks @TillHelge the first solution worked a treat. Didn't know the browser would effectively "concatenate" in that way.

Comment: @AdrianPatterson If my answer helps you should accept it :)

Comment: Apologies @jh314 I didn't know the procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function:

```
print_r(urldecode ( "%26" ));
```

will print out:

```
&
```